# Find f '($π\over2$) by solving integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

Hello can you help me please with this problem about integrals, I don't know how to  solve **g(x)**, or, how can I find **f '**($π\over2$). [Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnxel.jpg)
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax (LaTeX) for formatting. And what is $\operatorname{sen}$?

Comment: Sorry for that, sen means sin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=F(g(x))$ where
$$F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+t^3} }dt$$
and $g(x)=G(\cos x)$ where, again, $G$ is defined by
$$G(x)=\int_0^x \big( 1+\sin (t^2) \big)dt$$
By the FTC we have that 
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+x^3} }$$
and that $G'(x)=1+\sin (x^2)$.

Now, by the *chain rule*, we have that
$$g'(x)=G'(\cos x)\cos' x = -G'(\cos x)\sin x = -\big( 1+\sin (\cos^2 x) \big) \sin x$$
Therefore
$$f'(\tfrac{\pi}{2})=F'(g(\tfrac{\pi}{2}))g'(\tfrac{\pi}{2})=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+(g(\tfrac{\pi}{2}))^3} } g'(\tfrac{\pi}{2})=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+0^3} } (-1)=-1$$

Comment: Thank you friend, that's correct, -1 is the answer, but how do you know that g(π/2) is   0, solving without an calculator?

Comment: $g(\tfrac{\pi}{2})=G(\cos \tfrac{\pi}{2})=G(0)$ and $G(0)$ is zero since $$\int_0^0 \big( 1+\sin (t^2) \big)dt=0$$ and in general $$\int_a^a f(x)dx=0$$

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;F,G\;$ be s.t. $\;F'=f\,,\,\,G'=g\;$ (primitive functions), then:

$$f(x)=F(g(x))-F(0)\;,\;\;g(x)=G(\cos x)-G(0)\implies$$

$$f'(x)=F'(g(x))\,g'(x)=f(g(x))\,g'(x)\;,\;\;g'(x)=G'(\cos x)\,(\cos x)'=g(\cos x)\,(-\sin x)$$

Now put all the above together, justify things and end the solution.